# Problems with virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, git, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've been trying to install virtualenvwrapper/virtualenv. First I have them installed using pip install virtualenv from git bash. For some reason pip saves my files not in **`/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`** but in my Python Scripts folder. Accounting for this I setup my **`.bashrc`** as follows:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export MSYS_HOME=/c/msys/1.0
source C:/Python27/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

When I go to setup a virtualenv in gitbash with mkvirtualenv I get the following errors:

```
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not run "c:\Users\Martin\.virtualenvs\premkvirtualenv": [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not run "c:\Users\Martin\.virtualenvs\preactivate": [Error 2] The system could not find the file specified 
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not run "c:\Users\Martin\.virtualenvs\test\Scripts\preactivate": [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I looked to see if I have the files and I do. I'm running on Python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so this was a pain, I found out the hard way that virtualenv doesn't like Windows. Here's how I fixed the problem:

First I needed to  directly download the mktemp.exe for MSYS and place it in the corresponding Git/bin directory, my main problem had to do with GitBash didn't have the MSYSTEM environment set to MINGW32. To make it work in my .bashrc I simply replaced export `MSYS_HOME=/c/MinGW/msys/1.0` with export `MSYS_HOME=/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git` or wherever you installed Git.

Comment: I too got into difficulties when using `git-bash` on Windows. I am happy that I have migrated to `git-for-windows` sdk. https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/releases